# how to modify the value of src attribute of <img> tag using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am parsing a html string fragment and changing the src attribute of image tags. (i.e. replacing paths that start with ".."

```
var hstr = $.parseHTML(str);
$(hstr).find('img').each(function(e){
var srcvalue = $(this).attr('src');
srcvalue = srcvalue.replace(/../gi, "");
$(this).attr('src', srcvalue);
});
```

then setting the contents of a div element by appending the result

```
document.getElementById('#section').append($(hstr));
```

but it is not working... can anyone tell me what is going wrong ?

Comment: your current code can be simplified to: http://pastebin.com/yV4CLd9P (implemented answers from below into it as-well to simplify things)

Answer (score 3):

Dont mess up pure JS DOM and Jquery. Use `$('#section').append($(hstr))`

Answer (score 2):

*Don't get confused with Jquery [(#ID)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) selector*, Use either

```
$('#section').append($(hstr));
```

or (*no need of `#` and use appendChild in DOM element*)

```
document.getElementById('section').appendChild($(hstr));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out append() not works in pure JS. I just didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

You should append the manipulated object, you are creating another object, also DOMElement object doesn't have `append` method.

```
$(hstr).find('img').each(function(e){
    // ...
}).appendTo('#section');
```

Using `prop` method:

```
$(hstr).find('img').prop('src', function(index, srcValue) {
    return srcValue.replace(/../g, "");
}).appendTo('#section');
```